# Less +F redirect new output to new file

Tags: linux, command-line

Is that possible to forward/copy all new output that coming to my.log to new file when it comes.

For example when I do less +F my.log I see tail of the file and it's waiting for updates.

So, what I would want is to redirect all updates to new file. To let it contain only new updates.

But if I do: less +F my.log > new.log. I end up having whole file again.

Answer (score 2):

For redirection, use `tail -f` instead of `less +F`.

```
tail -f my.log > new.log
```

If you want the file to start at the point where you run the command, use the `-n` switch:

```
tail -n0 -f my.log > new.log
```